# Sum of product of Bell number and Stirling number of the first kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)*B(k) = 1$$ where s(n,k) - Stirling number of the first kind;  B(k) - Bell number.

I've tried to use $$B(k)=\sum_{j=0}^kS(k,j)$$ where S(n,j) - Stirling numbers of the second kind;  However, the proof of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^ks(n,k)*S(k,j) = 1$$ isn't easier and i stuck dealing with induction step for n+1.

I'm allowed to use only simplest facts such as stirlings reccurence and Bell's definition + those that are easy-to-prove.

Comment: Done ! What is the next question ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: What facts are you allowed to use about the Stirling numbers? about the Bell numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Using formal power series and standard EGFs we get for the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k} n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!}
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^k
k! [w^k] \exp(\exp(w)-1)
\\ = (-1)^n n! [z^n]
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k}
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^k
[w^k] \exp(\exp(w)-1).$$

Now $$\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^k  = z^k + \cdots$$  and hence we
may extend $k$ beyond $n$ since  these values do not contribute to the
coefficient on $[z^n]$, obtaining

$$(-1)^n n! [z^n]
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{k}
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^k
[w^k] \exp(\exp(w)-1)
\\ = (-1)^n n! [z^n]
\exp\left(\exp\left(-\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)-1\right)
\\ = (-1)^n n! [z^n] \exp((1-z)-1)
= (-1)^n n! [z^n] \exp(-z) = (-1)^n (-1)^n \\ = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the following orthogonality property between the Stirling numbers for $n \geq k$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \left[{n \atop i}\right] \left\lbrace{i \atop k}\right\rbrace (-1)^{n-i} = \delta_{n,k}.$$
Then the sum you are after is given by 
$$\sum_{j \geq 0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \left[{n \atop k}\right] \left\lbrace{k \atop j}\right\rbrace (-1)^{n-k}\right) = \sum_{j \geq 0} \delta_{n,j} = 1.$$